# Display programatically created controls on Tabpage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a button, that when clicked it creates and displays various controls such as, text boxes and labels.

However, I want it to display on a Tabpage. At the moment it shows up on the original form background.

Comment: Please show the code that you have right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `this.Controls.Add(...)`, you'd add it to your desired `TabPage` instead with `tabPage1.Controls.Add(...)`.

Or, if you're creating a new `TabPage`, add the controls to that, then add the `TabPage` to the `TabControl`:

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage();
tp.Text = "New Tab";

TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tp.Controls.Add(tb);

tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
```